# Dimension.get('window').height returns screen height, not a device window height in RN v0.71.7

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

There's a strange behaviour that's been observed on some(not all) android devices that whenever using `Dimensions.get('window').height`, it is returning screen height since the Android Navigation Bar is also added to the total height of of the component.

Android Properties:

```
avd.ini.encoding                 UTF-8
AvdId                            Nexus_7_API_32
disk.dataPartition.size          2G
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot no
fastboot.forceColdBoot           no
fastboot.forceFastBoot           yes
hw.accelerometer                 yes
hw.arc                           false
hw.audioInput                    yes
hw.battery                       yes
hw.camera.back                   virtualscene
hw.camera.front                  emulated
hw.cpu.ncore                     4
hw.device.hash2                  MD5:121629bcfab97028767e9021d5e4cdd1
hw.device.manufacturer           Google
hw.device.name                   Nexus 7 2013
hw.dPad                          no
hw.gps                           yes
hw.gpu.enabled                   yes
hw.gpu.mode                      auto
hw.initialOrientation            Portrait
hw.keyboard                      yes
hw.lcd.density                   320
hw.lcd.height                    1920
hw.lcd.width                     1200
hw.mainKeys                      no
hw.ramSize                       1536
hw.sdCard                        yes
hw.sensors.orientation           yes
hw.sensors.proximity             no
hw.trackBall                     no
image.androidVersion.api         32
image.sysdir.1                   system-images/android-32/google_apis/arm64-v8a/
PlayStore.enabled                false
runtime.network.latency          none
runtime.network.speed            full
showDeviceFrame                  yes
skin.dynamic                     yes
tag.display                      Google APIs
tag.id                           google_apis
vm.heapSize                      128
```

React Native Component snippet:

```
<FlatList 
snapToOffsets={[...Array(props.count)].map((x, i) => (i*Dimensions.get('window').height))}
renderItem={() => (
<View style={{ height: Dimensions.get('window').height }}></View> //this is taking full-height = window + android navigation bar.
)}
>

<Flatlist/>
```

In the following image, the navigation bar height is also added.

[image: Android Navigation Bar]

Answer (score 1):

Try useWindowDimensions of react native

```
import {useWindowDimensions} from 'react-native'

const height = useWindowDimensions().height
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.71/usewindowdimensions

Comment: thank u for sharing but tried it already.